# What is the current (as of 1.8) most efficient way to reuse a variable that results in database queries in a Django app?

Tags: django, optimization, django-templates, database-optimization

I know of `with`, and I know you can write your own template tags for this purpose, altering the context variable. However, given these circumstances:

- Cannot alter an application you are reusing, and do not want to "monkeypatch" its views.
- You have multiple isolated blocks in a given template, whatever.html, and, say, a `blog_post` context variable that has a `categories` member. You reference this '`categories`' field multiple times in the template differently, for instance, you only want the first element in one place/`block`, and then you iterate them all in a different spot in the template.
- You want to avoid duplicating queries altogether.
- You do not want to enclose everything with a '`with`'/'`endwith`' block.

What would be the most efficient way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware) for the specific view and alter [process_template_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response) context just before it renders. I think that will help.

Comment: This would result in all views being affected, AFAIK. My question involves a highly isolated example. There is no point in sparing multiple queries in one single view if that means adding one to every view that doesn't even use it for rendering.